# Find the image of the object under the given transformation

Tags: geometry

Let
$f: \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3 $ an affine transformation given by:

$f(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(x_1+x_2+x_3,2x_1-x_2+3,3x_1+x_3+1)$
, the plane $\pi:x-y+2z=1$ and the line $(r):(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(2t+1,1,3t), t \in \mathbb{R}$

Find $f(\pi)$ and $f(r)$

**My Approach**:( I would like to know if this method is right or fails depending on whether the transformation is an isomorphism or not)

$f(x)=Ax+b$, where $x\in \mathbb{R}^3$,
$\begin{align*}A= \begin{bmatrix}
                1 & 1 & 1 \\
                2 & -1 & 0\\
                3 & 0 & 1\\
                \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}, b=\begin{bmatrix}
                0  \\
                3 \\
               1 \\
                \end{bmatrix}$

So $f$ is indeed an affine transformation, but it fails to be an affine isomorphism( becuase $A$ is not invertible)

$dir(\pi)=\langle(-2,0,1),(0,-2,-1)\rangle=\langle v_1,v_2\rangle$ then
$dir(f(\pi))=\langle Av_1,Av_2\rangle$

Then, if we choose $P\in \pi$ we have the equation of $f(\pi):(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(P)+\langle Av_1,Av_2 \rangle $

The same method would work for the line too, I suppose.
Or simply, choosing $P,Q\in (r)$ we have:

$f(r):(x_1,x_2,x_3)=f(P)+\langle \overrightarrow{f(P) f(Q)}\rangle$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plane is described by $\mathbf{n}^T \mathbf{ r} = 1 $ , where $\mathbf{r} = [x, y, z]^T $.  And $\mathbf{n} = [1, -1, 2]^T $.

Now $\mathbf{r'} = f(\mathbf{r}) = A \mathbf{r} + \mathbf{b} $ where

$ A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 1 && 1 \\2 && -1 && 0 \\ 3 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

$ \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 && 3 && 1 \end{bmatrix}^T $

Now the plane can be written in vector form as

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_0} + V \mathbf{u} $

where the columns of the $ 3 \times 2$ matrix $V$ are perpendicular to $\mathbf{n}$, and are also independent of each other.  Vector $\mathbf{u} \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ is the coordinate vector of $\mathbf{r}$ with respect to the spanning vector of the plane, which are the columns of matrix $V$.  Hence, we can take

$ V = \begin{bmatrix} 1  && -1 \\ 1 && 1 \\ 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} $

And $\mathbf{r_0}$ is any point on the plane, so we can take $\mathbf{r_0}= [1, 0, 0]^T$

Now apply $f$ to $\mathbf{r}$

$\mathbf{r'} = f(\mathbf{r}) = f(\mathbf{r_0} + V \mathbf{u} ) = A (\mathbf{r_0} + V \mathbf{u}) + \mathbf{b} $

And this simplifies to

$ \mathbf{r'} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 5 \\ 4 \end{bmatrix} + W \mathbf{u} $

where $ W = A V = \begin{bmatrix} 2 && 0 \\ 1 && -3 \\ 3 && -2 \end{bmatrix} $

Thus $\mathbf{r'} $ is a plane passing through $ [1, 5, 4]^T $ and having a normal vector equal to

$ \langle 2, 1, 3 \rangle \times \langle 0, -3 , -2 \rangle = \langle 7, 4, -6\rangle $

As for the line, its parametric equation is

$ \mathbf{r} = \mathbf{r_1} + t \mathbf{d_1} $

where $\mathbf{r_1} = [1, 0, 0]^T $ and $ \mathbf{d_1} = [2,0,3]^T $

So it image is

$ \mathbf{r'} = f(\mathbf{r}) =  f(\mathbf{r_1} + t \mathbf{d_1} ) = A (\mathbf{r_1} + t \mathbf{d_1} ) + \mathbf{b}  = \big( A \mathbf{r_1} + \mathbf{b} \big) + t \big(A \mathbf{d_1} \big) $

Now,

$ A \mathbf{r_1} + \mathbf{b} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 && 5 && 4 \end{bmatrix}^T $

and

$ A \mathbf{d_1} = \begin{bmatrix} 5 && 4 && 9 \end{bmatrix}^T $

Thus the image of the line is another line that passes through $\langle 1,5,4\rangle$ and has a direction vector $\langle 5, 4, 9 \rangle $

Comment: Thank you! Could you tell me whether my method is right or fails in some situations?

Comment: Yes.  Actually your method is exactly the same as my method.